# failed to create release artifact directory because it is being used by another process Azure-Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, agent

I have faced this error when I get a release. I am not able to figure it out why this is happening.

I have a service which run websocket api. When I stop the service, release is **successfull**.

The interesting thing is.
**project location:** C:\Projects\Platform360.RTLS.MapDisplay.WebSocket
**agent location:** C:\vstsagent\A4_work\r41\a

**service**
C:\Projects\nssm-2.24-101-g897c7ad\nssm-2.24-101-g897c7ad\win64\nssm.exe

**bat script:**

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"

:: Set the correct directory. Only %~dp0 does not work because of its trailing backslash
set HOME=%CD%

:: check for permissions first 
:: we need admin priviliges for NSSM
goto check_Permissions

:check_Permissions
    echo Administrative permissions required. Detecting permissions...

    net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
        echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed. Starting config tool
        goto startInstallation
    ) else (
        echo Failure: Current permissions inadequate. Please right click bat and run as Administrator.
        pause
        exit /B 1
    )
    pause

:: only gets called when we have admin priviliges
:startInstallation
  echo Installing service
  :: Set your service name and its description here
  set SERVICE_NAME=Platform360_Layout_WebSocket
  set SERVICE_DESCRIPTION= Platform 360 Layot Websocket App
  
  :: replace with the absolute path where node.exe can be found 
  nssm install %SERVICE_NAME% "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
  nssm set %SERVICE_NAME% Description "%SERVICE_DESCRIPTION%"
  nssm set %SERVICE_NAME% AppDirectory "%HOME%"
  
  :: replace app.js with the name of your script
  nssm set %SERVICE_NAME% AppParameters "app.js"
  
  :: optionally set the out.log and error.log paths which will be used for stdouts and sterr messages
  :: better use a logging framework like winston
  :: nssm set %SERVICE_NAME% AppStdout "%HOME%\out.log" 
  :: nssm set %SERVICE_NAME% AppStderr "%HOME%\error.log"
  
  :: Start the service
  nssm start %SERVICE_NAME%
  echo Successfully installed and started service %SERVICE_NAME%
```

The failed error log:

```
2022-03-11T07:11:36.9450868Z Creating artifacts directory: C:\vstsagent\A4\_work\r41\a
2022-03-11T07:11:36.9510404Z ##[error]Downloading artifacts failed: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.Artifacts.ArtifactDirectoryCreationFailedException: Failed to create Release artifact directory 'C:\vstsagent\A4\_work\r41\a'. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\vstsagent\A4\_work\r41\a\_Platform360.MES.Layout-dev\Platform360.MES.Layout-dev\56977\Layout\WebSocket' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectoryInternal(String fullPath, Boolean topLevel, Boolean allowDirectoryNotEmpty)
   at System.IO.FileSystem.RemoveDirectory(String fullPath, Boolean recursive)
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Delete()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.IOUtil.DeleteDirectory(String path, Boolean contentsOnly, Boolean continueOnContentDeleteError, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseFileSystemManager.EnsureEmptyDirectory(String directoryPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseFileSystemManager.EnsureEmptyDirectory(String directoryPath, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.RetryExecutor.Execute(Action action)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.CreateArtifactsFolder(IExecutionContext executionContext, String artifactsWorkingFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifacts(IExecutionContext executionContext, IList`1 agentArtifactDefinitions, String artifactsWorkingFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Release.ReleaseJobExtension.DownloadArtifactsAndCommitsAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Object data)
2022-03-11T07:11:36.9534828Z ##[error]Failed to create Release artifact directory 'C:\vstsagent\A4\_work\r41\a'.
2022-03-11T07:11:36.9541389Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifacts
```

Comment: I have faced this issue, when I was building/releasing and at the same time I had an file explorer or terminal on the directory (in your case C:\vstsagent\A4\_work\r41\a). Are you using this directory at the same time another way?

Comment: No, I dont use this directory any place,

Comment: Hello, If the answer was helpful, Please Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem